# Using Opencv to calculate the haar feature

Tags: c++, opencv, exception, feature-extraction, haar-classifier

I try to calculate **Haar feature** using opencv (Given an image).
 
**Input**: an image
**output**: haar feature
For that, I am using the FeatureEvaluator from OpenCV.

But I got an **exception** when I try to calculate one feature. 
Here is how I am doing:

```
Ptr<FeatureEvaluator> ptrHaar = FeatureEvaluator::create(FeatureEvaluator::HAAR);

Mat img = imread(image_path);       // image of size 2048*1536 correctly loaded
ptrHaar->setImage(img, Size(100, 100));
ptrHaar->setWindow(Point(0, 0));
double res = ptrHaar->calcOrd(0);   // get the exception here
```

Comment: And the exception message is...?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE8D2EF6C (opencv_objdetect249d.dll) in FeatureExtract.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to load/create some type of Haar feature, not just create an object. Try to load some Haar cascade classifier using [load](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#featureevaluator-read) method and than try to use calcOrd method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right. Only is missing is to read the CascadeClassifier previously trained. You can do this as follow:

`FileStorage fs( "cascade.xml", FileStorage::READ );`

//2) Then, create a FileNode to access the features:

`FileNode featuresNode = fs["cascade"]["features"];`

//3) Create the FeatureEvaluator, as you did in your first line

//4) Read the FileNode you have created:

`ptrHaar->read(featuresNode);`

And continue accordingly your code.

Note that ptrHaar->calcOrd(0) will read just the first feature rectangle, if you have more to read, you will need a loop, like this:

`FileNodeIterator it = featuresNode.begin(), it_end = featuresNode.end();`

```
int idx = 0;

for( ; it != it_end; ==it, idx++ )
{
    res = ptrHaar.calcOrd(idx);
}
```